# Android How to add auto update functionality without any user interaction

Tags: android

I tried to find out the solution to auto update my application automatically without showing dialog or notification to user based on the client requirement,User don't have to click or interact with application to update it should update itself automatically.Are there any ways to do it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is not possible. It is only user preference to update the app or not.

Comment: Thank you for answer but that's client requirement so that whatever the changes we will do they don't have to do anything to upgrade application.

Comment: it does not matted if it is client requirement, or not. The word `impossible` is the answer. (ok, there is an option, but you whether need to make your app a system app, which means make a custom firmware for the device, or using root permissions. But root is not an option if you want to distribute your app world wide)

Comment: It's not for distributing world wide its just for a specific client.Well if we can do it by rooting then how can we do it?

Comment: if it is not for worldwide, then you can just disable usage of outdated version, and force users to download and install new version.

Comment: Or is it possible if i will create another application to upgrade it automatically which will accept the request click it and download and launch it .Thankyou for your answer again

Comment: you can't install an APK programmatically. What you can do max is to launch installation process where the user will be able to click `install`

Comment: Well let me give you the context it's for a bank to display advertisement   .So it's will be not in smartphone it's  gonna be in big tv and there will be no interaction at all all will be controlled by server so if any changes required then we will be unable to do cause no one will be there to interact that's why thankyou.